# Theorem about uniqueness of the limit of function.

Tags: limits, proof-explanation

Given that $f:Df\rightarrow R, Df \subset R, a \in \overline R , a\in D'f, b\in \overline R, c\in \overline R$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=c$ then $b=c$.

There are two things I don't get about the proof, first one is:
If $a\in D'f$ then $\exists (x_n)$ such that $(\forall n\in N \ \ x_n\in Df\setminus\{a\})$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=a$.

Why does $a$ being a limit point implies that there must be a sequence that converges to it? And that the sequence is within the domain? I could imagine that the definition of limit point implies that some sequence must converge to it, but I still don't know why that is.

Second problem: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=b$ and $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=c \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=c$

Why is that, is there any proof or axiom for it?

Comment: What's your definition of "limit point"?

Comment: What is $Df$ and $D^\prime f$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin A point is said to be a limit point if within whatever neighbourhood of $\epsilon>0$  there exists infinitely many terms. But limit point concerns the set not sequence, so how does it translate to the sequences?

Comment: @parsiad $Df$ is a domain of the function and $D'f$ is a set of limit points within the domain (I think).

Comment: @user: Pick $x_n$ to be both in the domain and in the $\frac{1}{n}$-neighborhood of $a$. Verify that the resulting sequence converges to $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from comments you are dealing with metric spaces. So I will assume that, although the proof works for the topological setting as well (with some minor tweaks).

So say $(X,d)$ is our metric space, $D$ is the set in question and $a$ is its limit point, meaning for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $x\in D, x\neq a$ such that $d(x,a)<\epsilon$.

Now consider a sequence of real numbers $\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and apply the definition to each $\epsilon_n$. So for each $\epsilon_n$ we have $x_n$ such that $d(a,x_n)<\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}$. By [the Axiom of (Countable) Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) we can combine these elements into a proper sequence $(x_n)$. And I hope it is clear that the sequence has desired properties.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about metric spaces, I am studying real analysis and trying to understand, does the fact that a point $a$ is a limit point of the domain automatically implies that there must be some sequence from the domain that converges to $a$? And secondly, why does it always follow that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=b \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=b$?

Comment: @user: He answered the first question *explicitly*. Just replace $(X,d)$ with "the real numbers".

Comment: @user replace $X$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and $d(a, x_n)$ with $|a-x_n|$. That's because $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ is a metric space. The rest stays the same.